# Ubuntu Touch App: "Error opening shm"

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, qml, ubuntu-touch

I am developing an app for Ubuntu Touch, sometimes it crashes with:

```
t_shm() at lttng-ust-comm.c:886)
libust[4253/4256]: Error: Error opening shm /lttng-ust-wait-5-32011 (in get_wait_shm() at lttng-ust-comm.c:886)
libust[4253/4255]: Error: Error opening shm /lttng-ust-wait-5 (in get_wait_shm() at lttng-ust-comm.c:886)
libust[4253/4255]: Error: Error opening shm /lttng-ust-wait-5 (in get_wait_shm() at lttng-ust-comm.c:886)
UbuntuWindow - regular geometry
UbuntuWindow::handleSurfaceFocusChange(focused=true)
UbuntuWindow::handleSurfaceResize(width=1200, height=1862)
UbuntuClipboard - Got invalid serialized mime data. Ignoring it.
UbuntuWindow::handleSurfaceFocusChange(focused=false)
UbuntuWindow::handleSurfaceFocusChange(focused=true)
UbuntuClipboard - Got invalid serialized mime data. Ignoring it.
UbuntuWindow::handleSurfaceFocusChange(focused=false)
UbuntuWindow::handleSurfaceFocusChange(focused=true)
UbuntuWindow::handleSurfaceFocusChange(focused=false)
```

I have no idea what could that mean or where to even start debugging.
Apparently this error affects some other apps, but I couldn't google anything useful.
Can you give me some pointers about what could that mean and where can I start looking for an answer?

EDIT:It works very well on desktop, the problem is only on the device.
(Nexus 7, Ubuntu Touch Utopic)

Comment: You should join #ubuntu-app-devel on freenode and/or ask this question on http://askubuntu.com/
Is this on a device or a desktop?

Comment: It works very well on desktop, the problem is only on the device.

Comment: Is that log from the same session? Does this include logs from after a relaunch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a platform error, it isn't a bug in your app. See the upstream [bug on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/platform-api/+bug/1404302).